Measuring the torque of a 3 phase AC induction motor using a load cell
We are working on a project, modelling and simulation of a 3 phase AC induction motor. We are at the level of validation of our model. We have a sample motor and we want to measure some variables; speed, torque, and current to see if they correspond with what the model predicts. To measure torque we want to use a load cell that is a weight sensor to measure the force an arm of known length attached to the motor can exert on it, and record the data in Arduino but there are two problems. Firstly, we are not sure of what torque the measured value will represent (we think it's the starting torque since the motor stalls). Secondly, we risk damaging the motor because this type of measurement requires us to prevent the motor from spinning which results in very high currents. Please, how do we go about these?

Stall torque (speed=0) is just a single point on an interesting torque-speed curve. Also, as you point out, protracted measurements at stall can be hazardous to the motor. (Although I wonder if you have a way to operate at significantly reduced voltage.)
I think you'll want something more like a dynamometer or at least a rotating-shaft torque sensor. A torque sensor classically uses an arrangement of strain gauges to measure how much its shaft has twisted. You couple that between the motor and a brake (where all the mechanical energy gets dumped as heat). A dynamometer typically adds to that a speed sensor and the brake, and probably some signal processing. You can move along the torque-speed curve by adjusting the brake load.
There's also a completely different way to validate your model. You could visit various motor manufacturers' web sites and pull their published performance curves. I'm not sure, though, how hard it would be to get the parameters your model needs.

Thank you. We thought of visiting manufacturer websites as the first and cheapest way of validating the model. Some manufacturers do publish the performance characteristics of their motors. However, we are required to perform the experiments to validate the model ourselves.

I don't know if it's feasible for your particular motor, but you can also consider mounting the frame/housing of the motor so that it's free to rotate on good bearings, and use your arm and load cell to restrain the motor housing to prevent it from rotating.
Then you can use a load that allows the shaft to rotate while simultaneously measuring the reaction torque. There are small errors from bearing friction and possibly transients if the housing moves a little before your arm restrains it, but the steady-state torque should be very close to what you'd measure with a rotating sensor on the shaft instead.
It's a more involved setup, and you need to devise a load that can actually handle the mechanical power you will deliver to it, but it would allow you to measure speed-torque curves directly.

Thank you very much for the idea. It's a squirrel cage motor. We've been thinking of how to use a load that can allow the shaft to rotate too, and hopefully measure torque still close to the actual value. We have a way of ensuring we don't get transients so that the load restrains the arm, just how to prevent damaging the motor in the process
